# Melody from an anime I can't remember

Tags: music, angel-beats

I don't even remember the whole song.
Just a very, very small part of the beginning which goes [like this](http://www.noteflight.com/scores/view/b395503bbf22c81c29fa38c717825b78405980f5) I think:

[image]

But if you think you know what it's from, could you help me out?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! I signed up on that site (which seems necessary to see anything?) but then it just tells me *Sorry, you don't have permission to read this score.*

Comment: Same remark for me.

Comment: ok, I think I fixed it

Comment: @Bryan It's accessible now, yeah. This feels vaguely like it might be a Yuki Kajiura piece - look through the list of anime she's composed for and see if any of them are familiar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuki_Kajiura#Anime_soundtracks

Comment: It sounds a bit like [Solitude by the Window](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxAh8_E2xW4) from the [Noir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noir_%28anime%29) anime.

Comment: This is too vague. Could be [*Unjust Life*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJIfjTGDfOE) from *Angel Beats*, or it could be almost anything. For example, it could also be [*A Town With An Ocean View*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vD1yAEWpzeQ&t=0m11s) from *Kiki's Delivery Service*. Can you provide more info? Is the song sad, so-so or happy? What instruments were used? Where did you hear it? Anything might help.

Comment: If as @senshin said it is by Yuki Kajiura, it may be [*Himeboshi*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0d4A7lfLtM&t=0m40s).

Comment: It's that one from Angel Beats!!  Thanks so much

Answer (score 6):

"If one shoots enough arrows at the target, one is sure to hit the bull's eye." So true.

[image: Unjust Life music score]

<sup>Taken from [**MuseScore**](http://musescore.com/user/38921/scores/71613), CC Zero license.</sup>